# Efficiently find all elements of a List<string> that start with another string

Tags: c#, .net, string, startswith

I have a list of strings.  I want to find all of the strings that start or end with another string. At its simplest an example is;

```
List<string> allWords = new List<string>();

for(int index = 0; index < 1000000; index++)
    allWords.Add(index.ToString());

List<string> result = allWords.FindAll(x => x.StartsWith("10") || x.EndsWith("10"));
```

This algorithm scans the list from beginning to end. I need to perform this operation very quickly and O(n) is too slow.

What data structures (if any) are available to me to solve this algorithm faster that O(n)?

Comment: That's not possible.  You'll have to constrain your problem so you have a shot at indexing to make it faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unsorted `List<string>`, *there is no way to do it in less than `O(n)`*. However, you could use a different data structure. A [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (also called prefix tree) is particularly well suited for your need, as it has a `O(m)` search complexity (where `m` is the length of the searched prefix)

I have a C# implementation here : [Trie.cs](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/GemBox/blob/master/GemBox/Collections/Trie.cs) (actually, it's a trie-based dictionary, which associates a value with each key, but for your use-case you can just ignore the value; or if you prefer you can adapt the implementation to your needs).

Answer (score 0):

1. To find strings starting with a given substring, [sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the list, do a [binary search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the closest match, then scan adjacent strings to find others that also match the beginning.  That's log(n)
2. To find strings ending with a given substring, create a list of reversed strings, and sort that list.  Then to find a string that ends in a given pattern, reverse the pattern and look for reversed strings that start with the reversed pattern, as in step 1.